# AppleScript and .txt file

Tags: text, applescript

I need to have an AppleScript that will edit the contents of a given text file (generic structure) and delete the 5th character through 8th character, leave characters 9-20, and delete characters 21-32. For example:

Say this is my text file:

"
Qt&:$yp$shshshahahah$jsjsjajssjh
"

(Single line)

I would need to delete starting from the first $ to the next $, and then delete everything after (including) the last $. In this example, the end result would be this:

Qt&:shshshahahah

Thanks,
Isaac D'Keefe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a command like this in Terminal:

```
sed -Ei '' 's/(.{4}).{4}(.{12}).*/\1\2/' ~/Documents/file
```

Or if you need to use AppleScript:

```
set p to "/Users/username/Documents/file"
set input to read p as «class utf8»
set input to text 1 thru 4 of input & text 9 thru 20 of input
set fd to open for access p with write permission
set eof fd to 0
write input to fd as «class utf8»
close access fd
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would need to delete starting from the first $ to the next $, and
>   then delete everything after (including) the last $. In this example,
>   the end result would be this:

Based on these conditions you can split an string up into chunks using a delimiter/separator. Then to my understanding you only want to keep the odd items and remove the even ones (by index). So the following script will work as you described rather than working on the index of the characters.

```
set theString to " Qt&:$yp$shshshahahah$jsjsjajssjh "

set {oldTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "$"}
set textItems to every text item of theString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID

set filteredTextItems to {}
repeat with x from 1 to count textItems by 2
    set end of filteredTextItems to item x of textItems
end repeat

return filteredTextItems as string
```